# Calling Amazon Alexa APIs with JavaScript (for using AVS, not for skill development)

Tags: javascript, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to develop a JavaScript based app that will interact with Alexa.
How can I call Alexa Voice Service APIs using JavaScript? (I am planning to utilize XMLHttpRequest for AVS connection.)

There is only an example Java app and it's a bit complicated for me to understand it.

Please note that my need is simple, I am not planning to develop Alexa skills, but just call the API from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the official documentation. It is quite thorough. Please reference the following:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-a-website

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/content/avs-api-overview
(^ especially the Interfaces section)

Perhaps I misunderstand what you are asking, but that should be enough to get you up to speed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes